# SetDllDirectory LoadLibrary inside a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies, loadlibrary, setdlldirectory

Can I use C++ `SetDllDirectory` and `LoadLibrary` commands inside a C++ DLL to load another DLL? I have tried using them like this:

Executable calls the 1st DLL, 
then 1st DLL loads the 2nd DLL,
then 2nd DLL does the calculations...

but when I run the executable, I get this error message:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the applications support team for more information.

2nd DLL works fine when linked directly to Executable!

This is the code inside my executable:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    HINSTANCE hDLL_Link=NULL;
    SetDllDirectory((LPCWSTR)L"C:\\Users\\MC\\Documents\\2014_07_01a_FDD_VC2008\\test_call_DLL\\EXE_calls_Link_DLL\\Release");
    hDLL_Link=LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)L"Link_DLL.dll");
    if(hDLL_Link==NULL) std::cout<<"did not load"<<'\n';
    typedef void (*Ptr_OPS_Link)();
    Ptr_OPS_Link Ptr_OPS_Link_0;
    Ptr_OPS_Link_0=(Ptr_OPS_Link)GetProcAddress(hDLL_Link,"OPS_Link");
    Ptr_OPS_Link_0();
    FreeLibrary(hDLL_Link);
    system("pause");
}
```

this is the code inside the 1st DLL:

```
#include "Link.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void OPS_Link(){
    Link*Link_Ptr_Object=NULL;
    if(Link_Ptr_Object==NULL){
        Link_Ptr_Object=new Link();
    }
    if(Link_Ptr_Object==NULL){
        //can not throw inside __declspec(dllexport) functions marked extern "C" that's why std::cout is implemented:
        std::cout<<"Error: could not link to FDD DLL"<<'\n';
        system("pause");
    }
    delete Link_Ptr_Object;
    Link_Ptr_Object=NULL;
}

Link::Link()
:m_void_Ptr_ObjectByDLL(NULL){
    HINSTANCE hDLL=NULL;//handle to DLL
    SetDllDirectory((LPCWSTR)L"C:\\Software\\Octave-3.6.1\\bin\\");
    hDLL=LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)L"C:\\Users\\MC\\Documents\\2014_07_01a_FDD_VC2008\\Executable\\Release\\FDD_DLL.dll");
    if(hDLL==NULL){
        throw "DLL loading could not be done";
    }else if(hDLL!=NULL){
        typedef void (*Ptr_OPS_FDD)(std::string, int, int);
        Ptr_OPS_FDD Ptr_OPS_FDD_0;//pointer to procedure inside DLL
        Ptr_OPS_FDD_0=NULL;
        Ptr_OPS_FDD_0=(Ptr_OPS_FDD)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"OPS_FDD");
        if(Ptr_OPS_FDD_0==NULL){
            FreeLibrary(hDLL);
            throw "DLL exported function address could not be determined";
        }else{
            //run the procedure inside DLL:
            Ptr_OPS_FDD_0("FDD_INPUT_Truss_Bridge_Data2_Ambient_Inch_11Channels_77824Samples_SamplingFreq_256Hz.txt",11,256);//LabScaleTruss
            //Ptr_OPS_FDD_0("FDD_INPUT_Ambient_EW_15Channels_3000Samples_SamplingFreq_20Hz.txt",15,20);//AmbientEW
            //Ptr_OPS_FDD_0("FDD_INPUT_Meriden_3Channels(3_5_8)_3686400Samples_SamplingFreq_2048Hz.txt",3,2048);//MeridenBridge
            FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your main() function doesn't do any checking to see if the function exists. Also, your main() function just ignores the error if the library cannot be loaded -- instead all you do is a `cout`. Also, do not pass parameters such as `std::string` across module boundaries, as you're doing . Do a search on SO for the reasons not to do this `typedef void (*Ptr_OPS_FDD)(std::string, int, int);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things in your code that can cause failure:

1. You do not exit if the DLL cannot be loaded:
2. You are passing objects that internally use dynamic allocation, and thus will use the heap manager.

For `1.` above, your main() function only does a simple `cout` if the library cannot be found.  However instead of exiting, the `main` function proceeds as if the library was found.

For `2.` above, passing `std::string` as a parameter to a DLL function is error prone and not recommended unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.  The reason it is error prone is

- The DLL that contains the function call may have been built with a different set of options than the DLL that calls the function.  These differing options could cause a difference in the way that `std::string` is implemeted, how it's layed out in memory, etc.
- The DLL that contains the function call may have been built by a different version of the compiler than the DLL that calls the function.  Again, same issue with differing implementations of `std::string`
- The DLL's and modules using std::string may not have been built using the `DLL version` of the C runtime library.  If the DLL's/modules are not built and linked using the DLL version of the runtime library, the DLL will be using a different heap than the module.  Any operation on std::string will be invalid, due to differing memory heaps being used.

So in a nutshell, unless you can *guarantee* that

1. You are building the modules and DLL's with the exact same version of the compiler and compiler options.
2. You are linking all modules to the DLL version of the runtime library.

Then passing `std::string` as a parameter, and in general, passing any object that maintains dynamically allocated memory, may or will lead to runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the inadequate error handling and using the standard library across module boudaries ,there are two other things to consider.

**Can I use SetDllDirectory in a dll to ... ?**

Yes you can ,but you SHOULDN'T ! (BUGS waiting to happen).

Why ? because the only entity that is responsable for changing environment is the main-application.
Library code (static or dll) doesn't know in which application it's going to be used.
It might work correctly in some programs and it may fail in others.

**Can I use C++ LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary in a dll to ... ?**

Yes you can ,but don't use them in the dllmain function since it can deadlock your program.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, and showed how here:

I changed the code inside executable and 1st DLL like below, to consider error handling, and also I added the "`return 0;`" now the executable links to 1st DLL and it works perfect... Actually the problem was that `main` needed to `return` something...I raplaced all the "`std::string`" with "`char*`" at the DLL boundaries...By the way, the reason that I want to develop two DLLs and I'm using "`SetDllDirectory`" inside the 1st one is that I want to call a DLL with a C# GUI, and the problem is that there is no "`SetDllDirectory`" command available in C#, therefore, I came up with the idea of developing two DLLs, inside first DLL, I will use "`SetDllDirectory`" to take care of the required dependencies (DLL is dependent on Octave and Octave Bin directory) and then I developed a 2nd DLL which carries out the actual computations...I know that there are some methods like "`[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]`" and from there we can use "`SetDllDirectory`" in C# but that method looks painful.

The corrected code inside executable:

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    try{
        HINSTANCE hDLL_Link=NULL;
        hDLL_Link=LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)L"Link_DLL.dll");
        if(hDLL_Link==NULL){
            throw "Link DLL did not load";
        }else{
            typedef void (*Ptr_OPS_Link)();
            Ptr_OPS_Link Ptr_OPS_Link_0=NULL;
            Ptr_OPS_Link_0=(Ptr_OPS_Link)GetProcAddress(hDLL_Link,"OPS_Link");
            if(Ptr_OPS_Link_0==NULL){
                throw "Link DLL exported function not found";
                FreeLibrary(hDLL_Link);
            }else{
                Ptr_OPS_Link_0();
                FreeLibrary(hDLL_Link);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(char*char_Ptr_Exception){
        std::cerr<<"Error: "<<char_Ptr_Exception<<'\n';
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The corrected code inside 1st DLL:

```
    #include "Link.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void OPS_Link(){
    Link*Link_Ptr_Object=NULL;
    if(Link_Ptr_Object==NULL){
        Link_Ptr_Object=new Link();
    }
    if(Link_Ptr_Object==NULL){
        ////can not throw inside __declspec(dllexport) functions marked extern "C" that's why std::cout is implemented:
        //std::cout<<"Error: could not link to FDD DLL"<<'\n';
        system("pause");
    }
    delete Link_Ptr_Object;
    Link_Ptr_Object=NULL;
}

Link::Link()
:m_void_Ptr_ObjectByDLL(NULL){
    HINSTANCE hDLL=NULL;//handle to DLL
    SetDllDirectory((LPCWSTR)L"C:\\Software\\Octave-3.6.1\\bin\\");
    //path relative to executable (C# executable or C++ executable)
    hDLL=LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)L"FDD_DLL.dll");
    if(hDLL==NULL){
        throw "FDD DLL did not load";
    }else if(hDLL!=NULL){
        typedef void (*Ptr_OPS_FDD)(char*, int, int);
        Ptr_OPS_FDD Ptr_OPS_FDD_0;//pointer to procedure inside DLL
        Ptr_OPS_FDD_0=NULL;
        Ptr_OPS_FDD_0=(Ptr_OPS_FDD)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"OPS_FDD");
        if(Ptr_OPS_FDD_0==NULL){
            throw "FDD DLL exported function not found";
            FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        }else{
            //run the procedure inside DLL:
            Ptr_OPS_FDD_0("FDD_INPUT_Truss_Bridge_Data2_Ambient_Inch_11Channels_77824Samples_SamplingFreq_256Hz.txt",11,256);//LabScaleTruss
            //Ptr_OPS_FDD_0("FDD_INPUT_Ambient_EW_15Channels_3000Samples_SamplingFreq_20Hz.txt",15,20);//AmbientEW
            //Ptr_OPS_FDD_0("FDD_INPUT_Meriden_3Channels(3_5_8)_3686400Samples_SamplingFreq_2048Hz.txt",3,2048);//MeridenBridge
            FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post it as an _answer_. Answers are meant to _answer_ questions, while _questions_ are _questions_, not _answers_!