# C++ dll with other dll as dependency (SDL2)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

i'm working on a C++ project with Visual Studio 2017.

I have SDL2 installed in a custom directory (not in `PATH`).

I'm creating a DLL which uses SDL2.

I added the SDL2 directory in the project properties (`VC++ Directories -> Library Directories`, I also tried with `Reference Directories`) and it compile correctly.

Then in the Core program, I load my DLL with `LoadLibraryA` and it fail (`getLastError()` tell me error 126).

I looked with **Dependency Walker** and it cannot find **SDL2.DLL**.

I also looked with **Process Monitor**, I saw it first looked for `SDL2.dll` in the current directory, then all directories in the `PATH` environment variable. Since SDL2 is not in a `PATH` directory, the loading fail, end of the story, **me is sad**.

Of course I could add the SDL2 installation directory to the `PATH` variable, but I don't want to, because of reasons.

Is there something I should change in my configuration?

Thanks.

**SOLUTION:**

I found a workaround.

My Core program load `lib.dll`, which needs `SDL2.dll`.

Instead I can create another dll, like `libloader.dll`. In this one I use `SetDllDirectory` to tell where is located `SDL2.dll`, and then I use `LoadLibraryA` to load `lib.dll`.

Since I have a single entry point in `lib.dll`, I just have to wrap it in the `libloader.dll` entry point.

That way, I will never have to put the location of `SDL2.dll` in the Core.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If the dll has dependency, it only search for the dll name and not for absolute? So I have to set my PATH? I'm kindda sad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I did something like this with `SetDllDirectory`:

```
try{
    /////////////////set dependencies subfolder relative path:
    SetDllDirectory((LPCWSTR)L".\\FDD_DLL_Dependencies\\");
    /////////////////load FDD DLL:
    HINSTANCE hDLL_FDD_DLL=NULL;
    hDLL_FDD_DLL=LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)L"FDD_DLL.dll");
    if(hDLL_FDD_DLL==NULL){
        throw "FDD DLL did not load";
    }
}
catch(char*char_Ptr_Exception){
    std::cerr<<"Error: "<<char_Ptr_Exception<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: Well in this case it's pretty much the same than with the PATH, I have to tell "directly" the Core where he can find SDL2.dll

Comment: @Ludonope Right, compiler doesn't know where the dependency DLL is, unless somehow you specify.

Comment: @Ludonope I'm not sure why it is not possible for you, maybe your project has specific requirements.

Comment: I have my Core program, and then a lib.dll which uses sdl2.dll. All I want is when I LoadLibraryA on lib.dll, lib.dll tell where to find sdl2.dll. And not putting the SDL2.dll folder in PATH, or in the Core program. Maybe there is an option in VS17, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Ludonope [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24999520/4838962) and its corresponding [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25001609/4838962) might help you.

Comment: Oh yeah, I can do 2 dll instead of one, and the first loaded just load the second one, while setting the DllDirectory, nice !

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this by using SetDllDirectory; see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx

(Note that this is somewhat non-standard behavior, and you need to be careful about security implications if you do this, but just to note it.)